# Pass computed style to children in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to pass the computed style of a React component to its children?

It would be very handy for me to access the `<Parent />` computed style from `<Child />`'s props.

Also, each time the parent component changes, the child must receive updated CSS properties (say the user resizes the window and the parent's width is set to `50vw`, then the child component will receive the updated size in pixels).

**Pseudocode:**

```
// App.jsx
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Parent>
        <Child />
        <Child />
      </Parent>
    );
  }
}
```

```
// Child.jsx
class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Parent's margin-top: {this.props.parentComputedStyle.marginTop}</h1>
  }
}
```

Is this possible? Do i need a third-party library?

---

### Edit 1

Came up with some sample code to explain my problem at best:

```
import React, { Component, Children, cloneElement } from 'react';

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div {...this.props}>
        {this.props.children.map((child, index) => {
          return (
            cloneElement(child, {
              key: index.toString(),
              parentComputedStyle: this.props.style
            })
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <p>Parent width is {this.props.parentComputedStyle.width}</p>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Styles</h1>
        <Parent
          style={{
            width: '50vw',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 128, 0, 0.4)',
            marginTop: '10px'
          }}
        >
          <Child />
          <Child />
          <Child />
        </Parent>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here the Child component renders "50vh" on screen, i'd like to have that value in pixels (the computed style, not the react style object).

Comment: You can use [props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: Yes but how? i tried `window.getComputedStyle(this.refs.childRef)` but inside the parent's render method throws an error.

Comment: You're doing `{this.props.parentComputedStyle.marginTop}` so you need to pass your style object to `<Children>` like `<Children parentComputedStyle={myStyleObject}>` and in order to update the components you should set your styles in your parent component state.

Comment: The problem is that if i set the state in the `render` method, it throws error, if i set the state with the CSS in the `componentDidUpdate` method, it enters an infinite call loop (because state changes calls the `render` again, and it calls the lifecycle method and so on..).

Comment: And what triggers the update of the css object? I mean, an event like a click, a user input?

Comment: Any change from the Parent down to its Child tree (also children of children) that actually change the visible CSS should inject the new props. basically it's like a *real time* CSS object

Comment: The only problem that I see is that you can't listen to CSS to see if something changed. You need to keep calling `window.getComputedStyle` to get the computed values... so what you could do is call that method every time the component updates let's say in `componentDidUpdate` and then set the computed style into Parent's state but before doing it compare if the new computed style is not equal to the current computed style so you don't get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 7):

So there are a few different ways to do it. The first is to simply add in a class name and then write some valid css.

CSS

```
.cssClass > h1 {
    // do all the things
}
```

App.jsx

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Parent className="cssClass">
        <Child />
        <Child />
      </Parent>
    );
  }
}
```

The other thing you can do is to pass in a style object and reference it through props.

App.jsx

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const otherWay = { marginBottom: '5px' }

    return (
      <Parent>
        <Child style={{marginTop: '5px'}} />
        <Child style={otherWay} />
      </Parent>
    );
  }
}
```

Child.jsx

```
class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1 style={this.props.style}>Parent's</h1>
  }
}
```

Try to think of everything in one direction Parent -> Child, best to not try to go the other direction.